# Fortran Read into multiple variables

Tags: fortran

I am currently working on understanding the process of a mutliscale simulation built in fortran which was not commented very well, and coupled with my lack of knowledge about fortran is making this a difficult task. I'm primarily having an issue understanding one statement regarding the fortran read command. A skeleton of the statement is below.

```
read(somestring, *, iostat = iospara) outstring, &
(someint, somearray(index), index = 1, statenum)
```

Now somestring is read from an input file and has the form of:

```
'label     1 2'
```

where the pair of numbers depends on statenum which is read from a different line in the input file. For example if statenum = 2 then somestring has the form:

```
'label     1 2 2 2'
```

My question is how do the parenthesis in the output variable list affect the read statement? That would be the:

```
(someint, somearray(index), index=1, statenum)
```

I haven't been able to find any information on this looking through documentation of READ. This is in fortran 2008. I also can't really provide a full working example as the code is extremely large and my attempts to recreate this statement separately have not succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an *implied do*, you will find many  questions and answers about this feature on this site. Sometimes people call it also implicit do, but that is not the standard name.

It repeats the part before the index: `someint, somearray(index)`, for the values of the index `i` with values from `1` to `statenum`.

That translates the input list as:

```
outstring, someint, somearray(1)
```

for `statenum = 1`, and to

```
outstring, someint, somearray(1), someint, somearray(2)
```

for `statenum = 2`.

Note that `someint` should not appear twice in the same input list or its value will be undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to figure out how to refer to this statement and was having some trouble. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you say that `someint` would become undefined?